# How do I port for Android 2.3 Gingerbread?

Tags: android

I am looking for reliable data regarding app compatibility to gingerbread (android 2.3)
I cant seem to find any professional information on the subject and i predict that after its launch we'll see a rain of gingerbread devices manly tablets...

One needs to prepare :)

Thanks in advance

Guido

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, there is no Gingerbread, and hence there is no "reliable data regarding app compatibility". You can find out when it is released by watching the [Android Developers home page](http://developer.android.com/index.html).

Comment: Or even better, subscribe to the RSS feed at the Android Developers Blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/